# additional columns being created when using read.table

Tags: r, read.table

Since I can't provide the .txt file I'm using I can only describe the situation...

The text file has no missing values and is a tab-separated text file or at least it appears to be.  When I use tab separated delimiter it seems to be fine.  The column headers are provided with names that contain spaces (e.g.   Age of Parent).

When I load the data using the following line of code it looks like everything loads properly.  However I am ending up with a bunch of duplicate columns.

For example - ***"Age of Parent"*** will be relabeled as **Age.of.Parent** since you can't have spaces in column names but there will be a 2nd column that is identical with the values but has the name - **Age.of.Parent1**

**Question**:  What do I need to do to ensure that there are none of these 'Duplicate' columns being created?  The column Age.of.Parent1 is clearly not in the dataset, but out of maybe 20 columns I am ending up with a total of 30 (10 new duplicates with this '1' at the end).

```
read.table('mydata.txt', header=TRUE,  stringsAsFactors= FALSE, sep='\t')
```

Comment: You can use `check.names = FALSE` in `read.table`, but regarding the duplicate column issue, it is not clear without a reproducible example

Comment: I can reproduce this when I create a text file with two columns with identical names "Age of Parent" and "Age of Parent" and read it with `read.table`. You probably will have to carefully inspect your source file, at least those lines where the extra columns contain data. Possible traps might be duplicated tabs `\t\t` or removed end-of-line. However, without showing the data at least the top rows) this is all speculative.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to show how a data frame can be saved in a tab separated file and reading from it.

```
library(caroline)

Age <- c(20, 30, 50) 
Names <- c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3") 
df <- data.frame(Age, Names)
colnames(df) <- c("Age of Parents", "Names of Parents")

#writing the data frame to a tab delimited text file
write.delim(df, file = "foo.txt")

#reading the tab delimited text file 
#The argument fill is logical. If TRUE then in case the rows have unequal length, blank fields are implicitly added.
read.delim(file="foo.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE)
```

Output looks like this:

[image]